# Báscula magallan RS-232 - SASI, evento funciona en emulador pero no en la práctica

Tags: c#

Tengo un detalle al leer una báscula:

```
 puertos.Close();
        try
        {
            puertos.BaudRate = 9600;
            puertos.DataBits = 8;
            puertos.Parity = Parity.None;
            puertos.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            puertos.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            puertos.PortName = puertoBalanza;
           
            puertos.Open();
            puertos.Write("P"+ (char)13);
            
         
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Tengo el evento *puertos_DataReceived*, el cual está en el puerto. Aunque veo que en el emulador funciona correctamente, en la práctica no entra al evento. ¿Qué estoy realizando mal?

Comment: ¿Se muestra algún mensaje de error?

Comment: No, solo no entra al método

Comment: no retorna ninguna información

Comment: Debes enviar algún comando para que la báscula empiece a transmitir?? A mí una vez me pasó que el cable estaba malo :S

Comment: Según la documentación que busque se envía "W", pero no resivo nada, el cable esta correcto, porque lo verifico con otro programa

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo leer este POST
https://sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Más que nada dice que para utilizar en C# es más confiable utilizar el método

```
BaseStream.WriteAsync(info, 0, info.Length);
```

Y para leer la información yo hice algo como esto

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
int read = 0;
while (read < buffer.Length)
    read += await serialPinPad.port.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, read, buffer.Length - read);
Console.WriteLine(read);
```